# LocalStorage is commonly used by applications, so how to avoid removing value accidently?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, sessionstorage

LocalStorage is commonly used by applications. Doesn't that mean that your values could possibly be manipulated or deleted by other applications? Or is some kind of namespacing being utilised so that values are stored on a per-domain basis and not at risk of being meddled with? Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Doesn't that mean that your values could possibly be manipulated or deleted by other applications?"* - Given that it is unique per domain, different apps within a domain could mess with each other's data (perhaps by accident if a large company had multiple dev teams working on different apps/pages within the same domain).

Comment: To elaborate on @nnnnnn’s point, For a site like `github.com`, if I could run JS in my GitHub https://github.com/sideshowbarker/ area & used local storage or whatever there, I could mess with client-side data anybody else with a GitHub account had some app in their area storing, & they could mess with any of the client-side data I stored from my area—because we both would be running apps under the same `https://github.com` origin there. And the specs for the local storage API and basically all other client-side APIs for the Web platform do not prevent that. Because they are all per-origin.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Would you guys suggest appending an app identification to each localStorage value associated with my app?

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` is unique to each origin, so it **is** secure, and can't be meddled with by other websites or applications.

The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage) specifically says

> The localStorage object provides a `Storage` object for an **origin**.
>   User agents must have a set of local storage areas, one for each
>   **origin**.
>
> User agents should expire data from the local storage areas only for
>   security reasons or when requested to do so by the user.
>   User agents
>   should always avoid deleting data while a script that could access
>   that data is running.
>
> When the localStorage attribute is accessed, the user agent must run
>   the following steps, which are known as the Storage object
>   initialization steps:
>
> 1. The user agent may throw a "SecurityError" DOMException and abort
>      these steps instead of returning a Storage object if the request
>      violates a policy decisions *(e.g. if the user agent is configured to
>      not allow the page to persist data)*.
> 2. If the Document's origin is an opaque origin, then throw a
>      "SecurityError" DOMException and abort these steps.
> 3. Check to see if the user agent has allocated a local storage area for
>      the origin of the Document of the `Window` object on which the attribute
>      was accessed.
>      If it has not, create a new storage area for that
>      origin.
> 4. Return the Storage object associated with that origin's local storage
>      area.
>      Each Document object must have a separate object for its
>      `Window`'s localStorage attribute.

Note that ["an origin"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#origin) is rather specifically defined, but for local storage it means protocol, domain and port must match for two endpoints to be considered to be of the same origin

Comment: Why would the fact that it is a property of `window` necessarily mean it is unique per origin? A hypothetical `sharedStorage` object could also belong to `window`, couldn't it? (Of course you are correct that `localStorage` *is* unique per origin, I'm not trying to dispute that.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - sure, it's probably possible, but generally `window` is the global, none of it's properties are shared across other "windows", but I edited the answer

Comment: Well `.localStorage` *is* shared across multiple windows from the same domain, so... Anyway, I was just being picky about the wording, and the edited version is fine.

Comment: Would you guys then recommend adding some kind of an app id to each value stored in localStorage?

Comment: Generally there's no need for that, as most apps store data in a way that is unique to each user or something similar, and as localStorage is clientside there's no way other users can overwrite each others stored values.